# Extrapolating point values to raster, excluding NAs

Tags: raster, point, sf, extrapolation

I have a raster generated from drone imagery that has been classified into water (river channel) and NA (all areas outside the wetted channel). I have a point file running down the center of the river channel and in some cases along the side.

I would like to extrapolate the point values across all of the 1's, to create a new raster where the point values have been extended, but I do not want the extrapolation to extend across the NAs.

How might I do this in R efficiently?

In the photo provided, the colored points represent different types of channel units (pool, riffle, rapid, etc) and the black area represents the wetter channel or 1's.

[image]

**Structure of my points file:**

```
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  5588 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ CU_Number : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Fish_Site_: Factor w/ 1 level "UpperLemhi1_2019": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Site_ID   : Factor w/ 1 level "UpperLemhi1_2019": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ StreamName: Factor w/ 2 levels "Lemhi River",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CU_Type   : Factor w/ 9 levels "LSC pool","LSC Pool",..: 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
 $ Seg_Number: num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Reach_Num : Factor w/ 27 levels "1","10","11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Notes     : Factor w/ 74 levels "BoR 10","BoR 12",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ geometry  :sfc_POINT of length 5588; first list element:  'XY' num  -113.4 44.7
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "CU_Number" "Fish_Site_" "Site_ID" "StreamName" ...
```

**Structure of my raster layer:**

```
Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
  ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
```